# Javascript: Can't get element using $('id')

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to access a object by using $('id'), but cannot success.

here's my code :

```
function jumptopage(myOffset, mySilder, table) {  // javascript
    ...
    var oPageSlice = $(recordsPageName);  // -> stop
    var myURL = $("jumptourl").value; // -> -> stop
    ...
}
```

The program always stops at that two lines.
recordsPageName is 'records_page', and both "jumptourl" & 'records_page'
are really exist.
I can use 
"var oPageSlice = document.getElementById(recordsPageName);"
to replace 
"var oPageSlice = $(recordsPageName);"

And it will work.
But I still want to find the reason.

p.s. The problem also can be reproduced in the following .

It seems the same issue in my php code.

```
html[] = '<input type="button" 
onClick="setPerPageRecs($(\''.$this->aName['records_page'].'\')...'
```

In this situation, setPerPageRecs doesn't be called when i click the button
it seems that $(\''.$this->aName['records_page'].'\'  doesn't correspond
to the object.

Comment: The id selector is `#id`, not `id` …

Answer (score 2):

You need to add # to get a element by id. like this:

```
$("#id");
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Selector #ID](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/). It lacks the `#` to select an ID

```
$("#jumptourl").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

you missed `#` character to [get element by id](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) and use `val()` instead of `value`:

```
$("#jumptourl").val()
---^
```

to access by class use `$('.elementClass')`

Answer (score 0):

I presume `$("jumptourl")` is meant to be referencing an id or a class?

You need to use a `.` for a class, or a `#` for an id.

E.g.

`$(".jumptourl")` or `$("#jumptourl")`